# Adding disqus to post.html breaks the whole page in github pages

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I have such Github pages - https://github.com/Diyago/Diyago.github.io

Its created from a template using Jekyll. To add comments section, I created post.html with disqus code sniptset under __layour folder:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://https-diyago-github-io.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Disqus itself seems to work - fine, but the whole site content disappeared. 
[image]

But should this information as well:
[image]

How to fix the problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've sending your posts to the posts layout. You should add some frontmatter to your files or add a default to the _config.yml file.

Comment: Also, there is no data for your conditional of `site.disqus.shortname`. You will need to add this to your _config.yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this way in post.html

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post h-entry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <link href = "images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title p-name" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta">
      {%- assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%b %-d, %Y" -%}
      <time class="dt-published" datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">
        {{ page.date | date: date_format }}
      </time>
      {%- if page.modified_date -%}
        ~ 
        {%- assign mdate = page.modified_date | date_to_xmlschema -%}
        <time class="dt-modified" datetime="{{ mdate }}" itemprop="dateModified">
          {{ mdate | date: date_format }}
        </time>
      {%- endif -%}
      {%- if page.author -%}
        • {% for author in page.author %}
          <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <span class="p-author h-card" itemprop="name">{{ author }}</span></span>
            {%- if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif -%}
        {% endfor %}
      {%- endif -%}</p>

  </header>
  <link href = "images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <div class="post-content e-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

  {%- if site.disqus.shortname -%}
    {%- include disqus_comments.html -%}
  {%- endif -%}

  <a class="u-url" href="{{ page.url | relative_url }}" hidden></a>
</article>
<link href = "images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://https-diyago-github-io.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```